# Recommendation for validating Python class data?

Tags: python

I'm looking for recommendations for automated validation of instance variables in Python objects. The validation should occur immediately upon instantiation or setting.

For example, imagine a class like:

```
import recordtype
class TemperatureReading(recordtype.recordtype('TemperatureReading',
                                               ['lat','long','alt','temp'])):
    pass
```

I'd like to be able to constrain lat to +/- 90, long to +/- 180, alt >=0, and temp >=0 .

Writing getters and setters seems too un-Pythonic and tedious. Is there a better way?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Can't you do the validation in `__init__` or do you want the validation to take place whenever a user tries to do something like `reading.lat = 120`?  For that you can use `property`.

Answer (score 0):

Write getters and setters, but use Python [properties](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) so that it's less tedious for the user. You can do some simple metaprogramming, possibly with a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/344821), to make it less tedious for the class writer as well.